# Is "scattered" an appropriate adjective for describing things that happen rarely and intermittently?

Tags: word-usage

Is "scattered" an appropriate adjective for describing things that happen rarely and intermittently?

For example:

> 1 I have recently received scattered criticisms from my followers.

> 2 I have recently had scattered ideas about leaving school.

> 3 There are scattered speculations about his personal life.

---

In [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scattered), the only record for "scattered" is "covering a wide area". I don't think that this description implies this usage but I think it might be used in this meaning as well.

Comment: The word you're looking for is ***sporadic***, not ***scattered***. But that second term does get used in some very similar contexts, such as a weather forecast predicting ***scattered showers***.

Comment: Note that ***scattered showers*** doesn't really carry allusions to "rarely". Only to "not continuously in any single location", which simply arises from the already implied ***in various different places***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Can you please tell me about the formality of the word "sporadic"? It seems a little formal. Do we hear it in casual conversations?

Comment: The word ***sporadic*** is neither formal nor informal. Perhaps if you were talking to *children* (who don't have a very wide vocabulary) you might want to use a more common synonymous term such as ***occasional*** - or more significant rephrasing such as *I have received **the odd criticism** from my followers, I've had **a few ideas** about leaving school.* For your final example, it's not obvious to me what you want ***scattered** speculations* to imply anyway - is it "a few", or "widely varying", or *both* those attributes? Or something else?

Comment: About the last sentence I want to say both "widely varying" and  "a few".

Comment: I don't think either ***scattered*** or ***sporadic*** work very well for the final case. Perhaps ***There has been some wild speculation** about his personal life*. But that's all off-topic writing advice.

Comment: ...plus It's *still* not obvious to me why you'd want to explicitly qualify the speculation in the first place. Perhaps it's because I'm a Brit, so I favour "understatement" anyway, but plain unadorned [*There has been speculation about his private life*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=speculation+about+his+personal+life%2Cspeculation+about+his+private+life&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) works better for me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers For example, suppose that there is a guy in your workplace that all your colleagues are talking about his private life all the time. You may hear about him 5 times a day. But in an other situation, you may hear about his private life once per weak and also people are not sure about the things they say about him. I'm looking for an adjective to modify and describe the latter situation.

Comment: If (plural) *people* are speculating about something that's not publicly known, the implication is *usually* that different people have different ideas. Occasionally it might be useful to characterize any such speculation as ***widespread*** or ***occasional***, but probably not usually. See [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+been+*+speculation&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) showing the most common adjectives applied to "speculation" (where ***some*** is the only one implying "not much, but enough to be considered *significant* in context").

Comment: @FumbleFingers I could also see some examples of scattered speculations. Maybe its not that bad. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22scattered%20speculation%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1977,cd_max:2006&lr=lang_en

Comment: Also see [https://ludwig.guru/s/scattered+speculation]
"There has been **scattered but persistent speculation** on the topic since 2006, when fragmentary reports ...."
(*The New York Times*) http://www.nytimes.com/2010/11/29/world/middleeast/29missiles.html]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140667/discussion-between-fumblefingers-and-alireza).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can use "scattered" to describe things that happen rarely and intermittently.

Your examples, however, don't work semantically because something cannot happen both "rarely" and "recently". The fact that it's recent precludes it having happened often enough to establish a pattern of "rarely".

> I have received **scattered** criticism from my followers.

A common way of expressing the same thing that works with "recently" is *the odd*.

> I have recently received **the odd** criticism from my followers.

It's worth noting that "scattered" can also carry the meaning "varying", so a sentence like, "*I have received scattered criticisms from my followers*" is ambiguous and would more likely be understood to mean you've received *criticisms of various types*, perhaps some mild criticisms and some harsh, or criticisms about different things.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes.

It's common to say "he received scattered criticism" or "he had scattered ideas about ..."

When used literally, "scattered" means not simply "covering a wide area", but covering a wide area in an irregular or uneven way. If you carefully placed, say, coins, in a neat pattern on a table, in precise rows and columns, they might cover a large area of the table, but we wouldn't say they were "scattered". If, on the other hand, you took a handful of coins and threw them on the table so that they fell in a very irregular pattern, you could say "the coins were scattered on the table".

Thus, "scattered criticism from my followers" means that most said positive or neutral things, but a few here and there, in no clear pattern, said negative things.